# Modular Java plugin system using Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

We have a set of interfaces e.g BookingInterface, InvoiceInterface,PaymentInterface that are implemented by different business processes

e.g

```
Business1BookingInterface implements BookingInterface {
}
Business1InvoiceInterface implements InvoiceInterface {
} 
Business2BookingInterface implements BookingInterface {
}
Business2InvoiceInterface implements InvoiceInterface {
}
```

We are looking at making each business process a Plugin that implements the set of interfaces exposed.

In our rest API we would like a particular plugin interface injected into our service

e.g

```
 @Inject
public BillingService(Configuration configuration,
                      EventDispatcher eventDispatcher,
                      Map<String,PluginInterface> theCorrectInterfaceImplementation) {
```

}

I am looking up MapBindings, AssistedInjection and FactoryModuleBuilder but not sure as to how do i get the right Guice setup to inject the required plugin interface at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MapBinder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) (as one of the [Multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings) features) is the right call for a plugin-style interface. FactoryModuleBuilder is an implementation detail of Assisted Injection, which is just a way to *mix explicit constructor parameters with Guice-provided constructor parameters*. If you don't need to do that, then you don't need assisted injection.

You'll still need to set up those bindings in a module:

```
public Business1Module extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, BookingInterface> bookingBinder =
        MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, BookingInterface.class);
    bookingBinder.addBinding("business1").to(Business1BookingInterface.class);
    MapBinder<String, InvoiceInterface> invoiceBinder =
        MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, InvoiceInterface.class);
    invoiceBinder.addBinding("business1").to(Business1InvoiceInterface.class);
  }
}
```

...and then install that Module in your injector.

```
Injector yourInjector = Guice.createInjector(/*...*/,
    new Business1Module(), new Business2Module());
```

The upshot is that you don't need to aggregate those dependencies yourself, and that Guice won't complain about multiple conflicting bindings to `Map<String, BookingInterface>` or `Map<String, InvoiceInterface>` (etc)...they will be automatically combined into one big map each.

Other notes:

1. Multibindings is in a separate JAR, so don't forget to install that on your classpath.
2. This might be an excellent reason to use [Modules with constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35833660/1426891):

   ```
   Injector yourInjector = Guice.createInjector(/*...*/,
   new BusinessModule("business1",
       Business1BookingInterface.class, Business1InvoiceInterface.class),
   new BusinessModule("business2",
       Business2BookingInterface.class, Business2InvoiceInterface.class));
   ```

Comment: Can i use providers along with Multibinding? to avoid circular dependencies?

Comment: I injected the services using a provider  Map<String,Provider<InvoiceInterface>> invoiceMap and things are working well. No more circular dependencies.